# Openwrt port forwarding not working

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, port, openwrt

I have a TP-Link MR3420 router with OpenWRT, and I can't forward port to a destination host in my LAN.

In firewall I have set like below:

```
config redirect
option name 'ssl'
option proto 'tcp'
option src 'wan'
option src_dip '109.241.232.66'
option src_dport '443'
option dest 'lan'
option dest_ip '192.168.1.104'
option dest_port '443'
```

What i do wrong ? Can you help me ?

What information  I must provide for you to solve this problem?

I have static external IP: 109.241.232.66 and set DCP on WAN.

Everything works fine except port forwarding.

And besides port forwarding, I have to open it on the router in the `Firewall - Traffic Rules section`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the official documentation from here: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/port.forwarding your config section should be:

```
config 'redirect'
        option 'name' 'ssl'
        option 'src' 'wan'
        option 'proto' 'tcp'
        option 'src_dport' '443'
        option 'dest_ip' '192.168.1.104'
        option 'dest_port' '443'
        option 'target' 'DNAT'
        option 'dest' 'lan'
```

But please check, if OpenWRT allow to redirect https (tcp:443) traffic.

Comment: You mean In Firewall - Traffic Rules section ?

Comment: Correct your setting as I provided, restart firewall and check if it works. Check generally, in documentation :)